# PHP DOWNLOAD RESULT

Tags: php, download

I need a guidance on how to fix this download result problem. Once I click the download link it taking me to a blank page. 
I tried to fix it but I cant understand where is the issue.

This is the result page where the students access after logging.

This result.php code below:

````
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('includes/config.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>JODA Int'l Result Management System</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" media="screen" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate-css/animate.min.css" media="screen" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lobipanel/lobipanel.min.css" media="screen" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prism/prism.css" media="screen" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" media="screen" >
        <script src="js/modernizr/modernizr.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main-wrapper">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="content-container">


                    <!-- /.left-sidebar -->

                    <div class="main-page">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row page-title-div">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <h2 class="title" align="center">JODA International School | Result Management System</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.row -->

                            <!-- /.row -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.container-fluid -->

                        <section class="section">
                            <div class="container-fluid">

                                <div class="row">



                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                                        <div class="panel">
                                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                                <div class="panel-title">
<?php
// code Student Data
$rollid=$_POST['rollid'];
$classid=$_POST['class'];
$_SESSION['rollid']=$rollid;
$_SESSION['classid']=$classid;
$query = "SELECT   tblstudents.StudentName,tblstudents.RollId,tblstudents.RegDate,tblstudents.StudentId,tblstudents.Status,tblclasses.ClassName,tblclasses.Section from tblstudents join tblclasses on tblclasses.id=tblstudents.ClassId where tblstudents.RollId=:rollid and tblstudents.ClassId=:classid ";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':rollid',$rollid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':classid',$classid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$resultss=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($resultss as $row)
{   ?>
<p><b>Student Name :</b> <?php echo htmlentities($row->StudentName);?></p>
<p><b>Student ID :</b> <?php echo htmlentities($row->RollId);?>
<p><b>Class:</b> <?php echo htmlentities($row->ClassName);?>(<?php echo htmlentities($row->Section);?>)
<?php }

    ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-body p-20">







                                                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                                                <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th>#</th>
                                                            <th>Subject</th>    
                                                            <th>Marks</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                               </thead>




                                                    <tbody>
<?php                                              
// Code for result

 $query ="select t.StudentName,t.RollId,t.ClassId,t.marks,SubjectId,tblsubjects.SubjectName from (select sts.StudentName,sts.RollId,sts.ClassId,tr.marks,SubjectId from tblstudents as sts join  tblresult as tr on tr.StudentId=sts.StudentId) as t join tblsubjects on tblsubjects.id=t.SubjectId where (t.RollId=:rollid and t.ClassId=:classid)";
$query= $dbh -> prepare($query);
$query->bindParam(':rollid',$rollid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':classid',$classid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query-> execute();  
$results = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($countrow=$query->rowCount()>0)
{ 

foreach($results as $result){

    ?>

                                                        <tr>
                                                <th scope="row"><?php echo htmlentities($cnt);?></th>
                                                            <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->SubjectName);?></td>
                                                            <td><?php echo htmlentities($totalmarks=$result->marks);?></td>
                                                        </tr>
<?php 
$totlcount+=$totalmarks;
$cnt++;}
?>
<tr>
                                                <th scope="row" colspan="2">Total Marks</th>
<td><b><?php echo htmlentities($totlcount); ?></b> out of <b><?php echo htmlentities($outof=($cnt-1)*100); ?></b></td>
                                                        </tr>
<tr>
                                                <th scope="row" colspan="2">Percentage</th>           
                                                            <td><b><?php echo  htmlentities($totlcount*(100)/$outof); ?> %</b></td>
                                                             </tr>
<tr>
                                                <th scope="row" colspan="2">Download Result</th>           
                                                            <td><b><a href="download-result.php">Download </a> </b></td>
                                                             </tr>

 <?php } else { ?>     
<div class="alert alert-warning left-icon-alert" role="alert">
                                            <strong>Notice!</strong> Your result not declare yet
 <?php }
?>
                                        </div>
 <?php 
 } else
 {?>

<div class="alert alert-danger left-icon-alert" role="alert">
strong>Oh snap!</strong>
<?php
echo htmlentities("Invalid Student ID");
 }
?>
                                        </div>



                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /.panel -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.col-md-6 -->

                                    <div class="form-group">

                                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                               <a href="../result/find-result.php">Back to Home</a>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>

                                </div>
                                <!-- /.row -->

                            </div>
                            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
                        </section>
                        <!-- /.section -->

                    </div>
                    <!-- /.main-page -->


                </div>
                <!-- /.content-container -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

        </div>
        <!-- /.main-wrapper -->

        <!-- ========== COMMON JS FILES ========== -->
        <script src="js/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/pace/pace.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lobipanel/lobipanel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/iscroll/iscroll.js"></script>

        <!-- ========== PAGE JS FILES ========== -->
        <script src="js/prism/prism.js"></script>

        <!-- ========== THEME JS ========== -->
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function($) {

            });
        </script>

        <!-- ========== ADD custom.js FILE BELOW WITH YOUR CHANGES ========== -->

    </body>
</html>


```

This is the Download page that will showing me blank   
download-result.php code below:- 

``` 


<?php
namespace Dompdf;
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
session_start();
ob_start();
require_once('includes/configpdo.php');
error_reporting(0);
?>

<html>
<style>
body {
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  table-layout: auto;
}

.fixed {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table,
td,
th {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 1px;
  border: solid 1px;
  text-align: center;
}


</style>
<?php $rollid=$_SESSION['rollid'];
$classid=$_SESSION['classid'];
$query = "SELECT   tblstudents.StudentName,tblstudents.RollId,tblstudents.RegDate,tblstudents.StudentId,tblstudents.Status,tblclasses.ClassName,tblclasses.Section from tblstudents join tblclasses on tblclasses.id=tblstudents.ClassId where tblstudents.RollId=? and tblstudents.ClassId=?";
$stmt21 = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt21->bind_param("ss",$rollid,$classid);
$stmt21->execute();
                 $res1=$stmt21->get_result();
                 $cnt=1;
                   while($result=$res1->fetch_object())
                  {  ?>
<p><b>Student Name :</b> <?php echo htmlentities($result->StudentName);?></p>
<p><b>Student ID :</b> <?php echo htmlentities($result->RollId);?>
<p><b>Class:</b> <?php echo htmlentities($result->ClassName);?>(<?php echo htmlentities($result->Section);?>)
<?php }

    ?>
 <table class="table table-inverse" border="1">

                                                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                                                <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th>#</th>
                                                            <th>Subject</th>    
                                                            <th>Marks</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                               </thead>




                                                  <tbody>
<?php                                              
// Code for result
 $query ="select t.StudentName,t.RollId,t.ClassId,t.marks,SubjectId,tblsubjects.SubjectName from (select sts.StudentName,sts.RollId,sts.ClassId,tr.marks,SubjectId from tblstudents as sts join  tblresult as tr on tr.StudentId=sts.StudentId) as t join tblsubjects on tblsubjects.id=t.SubjectId where (t.RollId=? and t.ClassId=?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$rollid,$classid);
$stmt->execute();
                 $res=$stmt->get_result();
                 $cnt=1;
                   while($row=$res->fetch_object())
                  {

    ?>

                                                    <tr>
                                                <td ><?php echo htmlentities($cnt);?></td>
                                                      <td><?php echo htmlentities($row->SubjectName);?></td>
                                                      <td><?php echo htmlentities($totalmarks=$row->marks);?></td>
                                                    </tr>
<?php 
$totlcount+=$totalmarks;
$cnt++;}
?>
<tr>
                                                <th scope="row" colspan="2">Total Marks</th>
<td><b><?php echo htmlentities($totlcount); ?></b> out of <b><?php echo htmlentities($outof=($cnt-1)*100); ?></b></td>
                                                        </tr>
<tr>
                                                <th scope="row" colspan="2">Percentage</th>           
                                                            <td><b><?php echo  htmlentities($totlcount*(100)/$outof); ?> %</b></td>
                                                             </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
</html>

<?php
$html = ob_get_clean();
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
//dompdf->stream("",array("Attachment" => false));
$dompdf->stream("result.pdf");
?>
````

Comment: Do you have any error ? Are you sure query have a result ?

Comment: with `error_reporting(0);` you won't have a lot of visibility on what's going wrong - turn on error reporting.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini yes sir. Result is showing normal, but when i click print it give me blank page

Comment: @jibsteroos  please how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You posted much code, but you wrong how create a pdf, you did that:

```
$html = ob_get_clean();
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
//dompdf->stream("",array("Attachment" => false));
$dompdf->stream("result.pdf");
```

When you write `$dompdf->load_html($html);`, the variable $html is empty so dompdf will show you empty result.
Example :

```
$html = <<<HTML
  <html>
      <head>
            <style type="text/css">
                /* Your document styling goes here */
            </style>
      </head>
      <body>
HTML;

while ( $row = $dbResult->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $html .= '<div class="form-control">'
                 . $row['row'] // all your data
             '</div>';
}

$html .= '</body></html>';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("example.pdf");
```

Use my example with your code and will work.

Comment: yes but it just showing me the  page with content but i cant print, this is the code

Comment: `<?php
namespace Dompdf;
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
session_start();
ob_start();
require_once('includes/configpdo.php');
error_reporting(0);
?>








  <html>
      <head> 
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" media="screen" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate-css/animate.min.css" media="screen" >`

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prism/prism.css" media="screen" > <!-- USED FOR DEMO HELP - YOU CAN REMOVE IT -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" media="screen" >
        <script src="js/modernizr/modernizr.min.js"></script>
         <style>
body {
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  table-layout: auto;
}

.fixed {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table,
td,
th {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 1px;
  border: solid 1px;
  text-align: center;
}


</style>`

Comment: `</head>
      <body>

<?php $rollid=$_SESSION['rollid'];
$classid=$_SESSION['classid'];
$qery = "SELECT   tblstudents.StudentName,tblstudents.RollId,tblstudents.RegDate,tblstudents.StudentId,tblstudents.Status,tblclasses.ClassName,tblclasses.Section from tblstudents join tblclasses on tblclasses.id=tblstudents.ClassId where tblstudents.RollId=? and tblstudents.ClassId=?";
$stmt21 = $mysqli->prepare($qery);
$stmt21->bind_param("ss",$rollid,$classid);`

Comment: `$stmt21->execute();
                 $res1=$stmt21->get_result();
                 $cnt=1;
                   while($result=$res1->fetch_object())
                  {  ?>
<p><b>Student Name :</b> <?php echo htmlentities($result->StudentName);?></p>
<p><b>Student ID :</b> <?php echo htmlentities($result->RollId);?>
<p><b>Class:</b> <?php echo htmlentities($result->ClassName);?>(<?php echo htmlentities($result->Section);?>)
<?php }

    ?>`